# Express.js Route Handler Execution Order

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I am trying to query some documents from my MongoDB database, then add the documents to an array, and then send it to a rendered view. However, it seems that the line that I have to render the page is getting executed before the db query is completed. Below is the code:

```
router.get('/blog/:username/:postid', async function(req, res, next) {
  var posts = [];

  await collPosts.find( { $and : [{ postid : parseInt(req.params.postid) }, { username : req.params.username }] }, function(err, docs) {
    docs.each(function(err, doc) {
      if (doc) {
        var renderedTitle = renderer.render(parser.parse(doc.title));
        var renderedBody = renderer.render(parser.parse(doc.body));

        var post = { postid : doc.postid, username : doc.username, created : doc.created, modified : doc.modified, title : renderedTitle, body : renderedBody };
        posts.push(post);
        console.log("0"); // EDIT
      } 
    });
    console.log("1"); // EDIT
  });

  console.log("2"); // EDIT
  res.render('index', { title : 'Post Results', Posts : posts });
});
```

I am very new to using Express, so if someone could help me to get the query to execute, and then the page to render, it would be greatly appreciated. Currently, where I log the posts array to console, the posts array is empty (as it is executing before the query is completed). Thanks

EDIT: When using the async/await approach (and some debugging), the 2 is now being logged to console before the 1 as expected. However, the 0 is being logged to console after 1 and 2. Could someone help me to resolve this please? Thanks

Answer (score 3):

This happens because I/O operations are asynchronous operations. You must wait for your db response and then send it back to client. You are sending `res.render` outside `find` callback, which results in sending response to client before your db returns something. Put your `res.render` inside `find` callback so you will be sure you will only send your response to client after db get your docs.

```
router.get('/blog/:username/:postid', function(req, res, next) {
  var posts = [];

  collPosts.find( { $and : [{ postid : parseInt(req.params.postid) }, { username : req.params.username }] }, function(err, docs) {
    docs.each(function(err, doc) {
      if (doc) {
        var renderedTitle = renderer.render(parser.parse(doc.title));
        var renderedBody = renderer.render(parser.parse(doc.body));

        var post = { postid : doc.postid, username : doc.username, created : doc.created, modified : doc.modified, title : renderedTitle, body : renderedBody };
        posts.push(post);
      } 
    });
    console.log(posts);
    res.render('index', { title : 'Post Results', Posts : posts });
  });
});
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply! I have tried this, and the posts array is empty upon the log to console in this case. I don't understand why it isn't working

Comment: Also, if I add something like console.log("1") inside the docs.each() scope, and then console.log("2") after that block, then the "2" is logged before the "1"; showing that it is still executing in the wrong order (if that makes sense)

Comment: ok, can you tell me which lib does `.each` method came from? because js and node doesn't have it by default.

Comment: I'm not sure sorry. I was just following the format from this article (about 3/4 down the page): https://blog.mlab.com/2013/11/deep-dive-into-connection-pooling/

Comment: Ok, try changing `docs.each(function(err, doc) {` to `docs.toArray().forEach(function(doc) {`

Comment: I get this error: TypeError: docs.toArray(...).each is not a function

Comment: Because it’s .forEach not .each

Answer (score 0):

I have been coding a lot in express lately, and sometimes the issue when querying the database is that it returns a promise. You can either provide a callback or use ES6 async/await as shown below. Hope this helps!

```
router.get('/blog/:username/:postid', async function(req, res, next) {
  var posts = [];

  await collPosts.find( { $and : [{ postid : parseInt(req.params.postid) }, { username : req.params.username }] }, function(err, docs) {
    docs.each(function(err, doc) {
      if (doc) {
        var renderedTitle = renderer.render(parser.parse(doc.title));
        var renderedBody = renderer.render(parser.parse(doc.body));

        var post = { postid : doc.postid, username : doc.username, created : doc.created, modified : doc.modified, title : renderedTitle, body : renderedBody };
        posts.push(post);
      } 
    });
  });

  console.log(posts);
  res.render('index', { title : 'Post Results', Posts : posts });
});
```

Comment: Thank you for the quick response! For some reason, even if I try this, the log to console still shows an empty array. However, I know that the posts array is getting elements added to it, because if i put the log to console inside the docs.each scope, it works fine